# Comparing file contents in F#

Tags: .net, f#, filestream

I wrote a quick and dirty function to compare file contents (BTW, I have already tested that they are of equal size):

```
let eqFiles f1 f2 =
  let bytes1 = Seq.ofArray (File.ReadAllBytes f1)
  let bytes2 = Seq.ofArray (File.ReadAllBytes f2)
  let res = Seq.compareWith (fun x y -> (int x) - (int y)) bytes1 bytes2
  res = 0
```

I'm not happy with reading the whole contents into an array. I'd rather have a lazy sequence of bytes, but I can't find the right API in F#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use the full power of F#, then you can also do it asynchronously. The idea is that you can asynchronously read a block of the specified size from both files and then compare the blocks (using standard & simple comparison of byte arrays).

This is actually an interesting problem, because you need to generate something like an asynchronous sequence (a sequence of `Async<T>` values that is generated on demand, but without blocking threads as with simple `seq<T>` or iteration). The function to read the data and declaration of async sequence could look like this:

**EDIT** I also posted the snippet to http://fssnip.net/1k which has nicer F# formatting :-)

```
open System.IO

/// Represents a sequence of values 'T where items 
/// are generated asynchronously on-demand
type AsyncSeq<'T> = Async<AsyncSeqInner<'T>> 
and AsyncSeqInner<'T> =
  | Ended
  | Item of 'T * AsyncSeq<'T>

/// Read file 'fn' in blocks of size 'size'
/// (returns on-demand asynchronous sequence)
let readInBlocks fn size = async {
  let stream = File.OpenRead(fn)
  let buffer = Array.zeroCreate size

  /// Returns next block as 'Item' of async seq
  let rec nextBlock() = async {
    let! count = stream.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, size)
    if count > 0 then return Ended
    else 
      // Create buffer with the right size
      let res = 
        if count = size then buffer
        else buffer |> Seq.take count |> Array.ofSeq
      return Item(res, nextBlock()) }

  return! nextBlock() }
```

The asynchronous workflow to do the comparison is then quite simple:

```
let rec compareBlocks seq1 seq2 = async {
  let! item1 = seq1
  let! item2 = seq1
  match item1, item2 with 
  | Item(b1, ns1), Item(b2, ns2) when b1 <> b2 -> return false
  | Item(b1, ns1), Item(b2, ns2) -> return! compareBlocks ns1 ns2
  | Ended, Ended -> return true
  | _ -> return failwith "Size doesn't match" }

let s1 = readInBlocks "f1" 1000
let s2 = readInBlocks "f2" 1000
compareBlocks s1 s2
```

Comment: gotta tell you, F# Web Snippets is awesome. I think it's really exciting, a true gem exemplifying what software can do (due credit to the F# compiler team as well for exposing the compiler service). BTW: The tooltip implementation is very nice (shows instantly, stays as long as you hover, and easy on the eyes), did you hand-roll it or is it 3rd party? If you're taking feature requests, easier copy and paste for snippits with line numbers would be good (though the fact that you can generate snippits without line numbers addresses this partly).

Comment: Didn't you meen if count < 0 then return Ended?

Comment: That was my next question: How to do it asynchronously? 

Let me make sure I understand your implementation. When you execute "let! item1 = seq1" you are blocking until seq1 is evaluated. This in turn blocks on "return! nextBlock()". nextBlock blocks on stream.AsyncRead. When the read finishes, the continuation "if count..." executes and returns an Item with the buffer and the asynchronous tail. If the two buffers are equal, you force the recursive execution of compareBlocks, passing it the tails. I think I get it. 

Question: when is the stream closed? Would it be better to use "use stream"?

Answer (score 6):

this will compare the files byte for byte and shortcut if there's a differences along the way. It will also handle different files sizes

```
let rec compareFiles (fs1: FileStream) (fs2: FileStream) =
      match fs1.ReadByte(),fs2.ReadByte() with
      | -1,-1 -> true //all bytes have been enumerated and were all equal
      | _,-1 -> false //the files are of different length
      | -1,_ -> false //the files are of different length
      | x,y when x <> y -> false
             //only continue to the next bytes when the present two are equal 
      | _ -> compareFiles fs1 fs2
```

Comment: @bartosz not sure I understand your questions. Were they meant for another otherwise try again and I'll see if I understand and can help further

Answer (score 1):

you must stream the files, just read them block by bloc, maybe `File and Stream(and it's descendants like StreamReader and so )`  libraries in .Net could address your need.

Comment: StreamReader seems to be specific to text files. I'm interested in binary files and I don't want any character decoding.

Comment: How is it better than FileStream?

Comment: Has many more specific functions for reading binary files in easy way

Answer (score 1):

As the others already said, use a stream for lazy I/O, for instance

```
open System

let seqOfFstream (fstream: IO.FileStream) = seq {
    let currentByte = ref 0
    while !currentByte >= 0 do
        currentByte := fstream.ReadByte()
        yield !currentByte
}

let fileEq fname1 fname2 =
    use f1 = IO.File.OpenRead fname1
    use f2 = IO.File.OpenRead fname2    
    not (Seq.exists2 (fun a b -> a <> b) (seqOfFstream f1) (seqOfFstream f2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything new in F# for this - I would just define a sequence that yields bytes using a `FileStream` underneath instead of using `File.ReadAllBytes`. Then you can compare two such sequences the "F# way".

Comment: I asked because there are sequence-returning APIs for directory listing, like Directory.EnumerateFiles. Nothing like that for file contents? I have to read buffers from FileStream and turn them into sequences?

Answer (score 0):

An adjustment to the accepted answer by Tomas Petricek. You asked where the streams are closed? They are not. Causing handle leakage and sharing validation issues in my case. I resolved this by moving the responsibility of opening and closing the stream to the calling method by changing the signature of the readInBlocks function
from:

```
let readInBlocks fn size =
[...]
```

to:

```
let readInBlocks (stream:FileStream) size = 
[...]
```

The compare-file method is then responsible for the disposing of the streams:

```
let compareFile (filePath1, filePath2) =
    use stream1 = File.OpenRead(filePath1)
    use stream2 = File.OpenRead(filePath2)
    let s1 = readInBlocks stream1 1000        
    let s2 = readInBlocks stream2 1000
    let isEqual =
        compareBlocks s1 s2
        |> Async.RunSynchronously                
    isEqual
```

The complete adjusted code:

```
open System.IO

/// Represents a sequence of values 'T where items 
/// are generated asynchronously on-demand
type AsyncSeq<'T> = Async<AsyncSeqInner<'T>> 
and AsyncSeqInner<'T> =
  | Ended
  | Item of 'T * AsyncSeq<'T>

/// Read file 'fn' in blocks of size 'size'
/// (returns on-demand asynchronous sequence)
let readInBlocks (stream:FileStream) size = 
    async {                            
        let buffer = Array.zeroCreate size
        /// Returns next block as 'Item' of async seq
        let rec nextBlock() = 
            async {
                let! count = stream.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, size)
                if count = 0 then return Ended
                else 
                    // Create buffer with the right size
                    let res = 
                        if count = size then buffer
                        else buffer |> Seq.take count |> Array.ofSeq
                    return Item(res, nextBlock()) 
            }
        return! nextBlock()
    }

/// Asynchronous function that compares two asynchronous sequences
/// item by item. If an item doesn't match, 'false' is returned
/// immediately without generating the rest of the sequence. If the
/// lengths don't match, exception is thrown.
let rec compareBlocks seq1 seq2 = async {
  let! item1 = seq1
  let! item2 = seq2
  match item1, item2 with 
  | Item(b1, ns1), Item(b2, ns2) when b1 <> b2 -> return false
  | Item(b1, ns1), Item(b2, ns2) -> return! compareBlocks ns1 ns2
  | Ended, Ended -> return true
  | _ -> return failwith "Size doesn't match" }

/// Compare two files using 1k blocks
let compareFile (filePath1, filePath2) =
    use stream1 = File.OpenRead(filePath1)
    use stream2 = File.OpenRead(filePath2)
    let s1 = readInBlocks stream1 1000        
    let s2 = readInBlocks stream2 1000
    let isEqual =
        compareBlocks s1 s2
        |> Async.RunSynchronously                
    isEqual
```